# Custom inputfieds crashes on return

Tags: react-native, react-redux

using this code to create multiple input text using custominputfield everything works fine and focus moves to next field correctly but app crashes on last field when I press return. can not figure it out myself please help.

```
<View>
            {
                fields.map((res, index) =>
                    <CustomInputField fildref={inputFieldRef[index]} placeholder={res?.placeholder} returnkeytext={res?.returnkeytxt} onSubmitEditing=
                    {() => inputFieldRef[index + 1].current.focus()} />
                )
            }
</View>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in the last field `inputFieldRef[index + 1]` is undefined, lest try :

```
<View>
            {
                fields.map((res, index) =>
                    <CustomInputField fildref={inputFieldRef[index]} placeholder={res?.placeholder} returnkeytext={res?.returnkeytxt} onSubmitEditing=
                    {() => {
                          if(fields.length - 1 === index){
                            inputFieldRef[index].current.blur()
                          } else {
                            inputFieldRef[index + 1].current.focus()
                          }
                     }} />
                )
            }
</View>
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends where you want the focus to go when the last field is submitted? If you want nothing to happen then you can do:

```
{fields
  .map((res, index, all) => [
    res,
    index,
    all.length === index + 1 ? false : index + 1,
  ])
  .map(([res, index, next]) => (
    <CustomInputField
      fildref={inputFieldRef[index]}
      placeholder={res?.placeholder}
      returnkeytext={res?.returnkeytxt}
      onSubmitEditing={() =>
        next && inputFieldRef[next].current.focus()
      }
    />
  ))}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
<View>
    {
        fields.map((res, index) =>
            <CustomInputField fildref={inputFieldRef[index]} placeholder={res?.placeholder} returnkeytext={res?.returnkeytxt} onSubmitEditing=
            {() => {
                  fields.length - 1 === index ?
                    inputFieldRef[index].current.blur()
                  :
                    inputFieldRef[index + 1].current.focus()
                  
             }} />
        )
    }
</View>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain your solution.